# Getting married in the US on ESTA with intent to return to foreign country

Tags: us-citizens, us-visa-waiver-program, weddings, german-citizens

I am an American citizen. I would like to marry the German with whom I currently live in Germany, and intend to return here after the ceremony in the US with my family.

I understand it such that we can get married with her visiting under VWP, so long as we return to Germany. We just need to convince the CBP that we intend to return.

However, both being full-time students, we don't have much in the way of proof that we intend to return. The rental agreement is under my name, not hers, and neither of us have work contracts. We can both bring proof of enrollment in our college, and a slew of other smaller things that show our intent to return, but nothing really "concrete" that I've seen listed on sites like this. Recommendations?

Comment: Note that she would be entering the US under the VWP, not ESTA. ESTA is a requirement to board an airplane under the VWP, but it's the VWP that lets her in (or not).

Comment: Related, but not quite a duplicate: [Are these intended activities legal to do in the USA under the VWP?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/140895/19400)  Also: [Getting married in the US on a Tourist Visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/134190/19400)

Comment: In Germany marriages consists of a civil ceremony and optionally a religious ceremony. The religious ceremony has almost zero legal impact but many families make it the main celebration. Have you considered to have the civil marriage in Germany and to attend a religious service in the US?

Comment: @o.m. the only benefit of that approach would be not having to give the purpose of the visit as "to get married."

Comment: So what exactly is your question, as I do not see one?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now until they clarify.